# How do I add NEW values in one table along with the values in another table to a third table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert, bulkinsert

I have three tables.  We'll call them Data, Period, and Type.  Data contains a record for each record in Type and each record in Period, so that the length of Data is the length of Period times the length of Type.

```
Type:
TypeID(primary key int)
TypeName(vchar)

Period:
PeriodID(primary key int)
PeriodName(varchar)

Data:
DataID(primary key int)
PeriodID(relational int)
TypeID(relational int)
Value(int)
```

From time to time new values will be added to Period, but Type should remain the same for the foreseeable future.  What I want to do is insert new records into Data for each new Period (PeriodIDs that Data does not yet contain), one for each TypeID.  So if there are 5 new Period records and 6 Type records, Data should have 30 new entries. I'm unsure how to do this concisely with SQL. Performance is not an issue since both Period and Type are reasonably small tables.

Comment: even when the answer here are correct, sound like you should create an `INSERT TRIGGER` in your table [CREATE TRIGGER (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms189799(v=sql.120).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Cartesian Product and a Subquery should do what you want:

```
insert into Data (PeriodID, TypeID)
select PeriodID, TypeID
from Period, Type
where PeriodID not in (select PeriodID from Data)
```

Note that your DataID column is assumed to be automatically generated, and the Value column will be null (so needs to be nullable). You may need to change the SQL if this isn't the case.

Comment: I think the sub-query should be referencing Data, not Period, no?  Otherwise `not in` will always fail.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are looking to get a cross product

```
INSERT INTO Data
SELECT P.PeriodID, T.TypeID, 'some value' AS Value
FROM Period P
CROSS JOIN Type T
```

A quick example of results

```
DECLARE @Period TABLE (
    PeriodID int
    )

DECLARE @Type TABLE (
    TypeID int
    )

insert into @Period
VALUES
    (1),(2),(3)
insert into @Type
VALUES
    (4),(5),(6)

SELECT P.PeriodID, T.TypeID, 'some value' AS Value
FROM @Period P
CROSS JOIN @Type T
```

Results

```
1   4   some value
2   4   some value
3   4   some value
1   5   some value
2   5   some value
3   5   some value
1   6   some value
2   6   some value
3   6   some value
```

Comment: Cool I didn't know about CROSS JOIN.  However, this is not quite what I'm looking for, as I want to only insert periods into Data that are missing from the Data table (newly added to the period table).  Never-the-less knowing about CROSS JOIN should allow me to figure out the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Just after inserting into Period table you can use statement:

```
insert into Data(PeriodID,TypeID, Value) 
select scope_identity(), TypeId, @DefaultValue From Type;
```

or you could use trigger if it impossible to add after insert of each new value to Period table in transaction:

```
insert into Data(PeriodID,TypeID, Value) 
select i.PeriodID, t.TypeId, @DefaultValue from inserted i cross join Type t
```

Note that your DataID column is assumed to be automatically generated, and the Value column will be filled with value of variable  @DefaultValue you have to declare before statement like this:

```
declare @DefaultValue int = 0;
```

Comment: So is `inserted` some kind of keyword? I don't see where it's defined.  If this requires being run immediately after the insert(s) to Period, then I can't use it.  I need to do an update to Data regardless of when the changes were made to Period.

Comment: Inserted is the keyword for data which been inserting recently for the trigger. You can use it only in a trigger. It will be triggered automatically before or after inserting into table Period and will automatically insert data into table Data which you need.
You could try to create trigger on insert to your Period table and add code above for a trigger.

Comment: In an insert trigger the `inserted` keyword refers to the row that has just been inserted.

Comment: @DigitalDan Correct. So if you require to do it in a specific time, not just after insert to table Period, then please use the example provided by Digital Dan. But anyway, I think that my examples can be useful for anyone who not banned or even require to do it just after the insert.